# Splitting Polygon using Polygon in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2

I want to split the polygon layer **Settlement** using another polygon layer **District boundary**.

How can I do this in ArcGIS ?

There are 64 districts adjacent to each other. Different part of a Settlement might be in 2/3 adjacent districts, which I need to split.

Comment: Use Intersect or Union with ArcGIS

Comment: can you give me more detail by image?

Comment: In ArcGIS use Split (Analysis) http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/split.htm

Comment: GIS SE is not intended to be a tutoring site. Questions are expected to show basic research and an effort to solve the problem. Please **edit the question** to explain what you have tried and where you are stuck. A google on "ArcGIS desktop overlay" should get you started.

Comment: @GISGE Please consider adding your comment as an answer so we can consider this question resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to split a polygon and export each split in separate feature class you should use [split tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/split.htm). Using [Intersect](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/intersect.htm) tool you Can intersect a polygon based on overlap  polygons.In this method the result will be save  in an output layer and attribute table of the output has information of overlap layer and the source layer.You may lose some features with this tools.Using [union](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/union.htm) tool you write all of features.It depends on your project Which of these tools are suitable for you.

Comment: Yes, split tool gave the expected output. Union gave some strange / fluctuating results. Only thing wondering is, I have to merge the splitted/separated shapefiles again in a single shapefile ! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

With ArcGIS, you can use the [Union](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/union.htm) or [Intersect](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/intersect.htm) tools. They will create an new feature class combining the attributes of both inputs. The [Split](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/split.htm) tool mentioned by @PredatorX is a nice option too, but it is only available with an Advanced license.